# How do I limit the range of commits reported by git log?

Tags: git

I'm trying to check what branches were merged into the origin between two commits with something along the following lines:

```
git log --merges --first-parent --oneline origin 7284b1a6dea454c2023efb709a31ee9dbcde8de6..79764fa47dde40ed8aecf203a606e64409e3f895
```

Where `7284b1a6dea454c2023efb709a31ee9dbcde8de6` was committed earlier than `79764fa47dde40ed8aecf203a606e64409e3f895` in the history of `origin`.

For some reason though, it's returning everything up to head rather than limiting it to the range of commits between those two SHAs.

[The docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log-ltrevisionrangegt) suggest it should limit it to the range though:

> Show only commits in the specified revision range. When no `<revision range>` is specified, it defaults to HEAD (i.e. the whole history leading to the current commit). origin..HEAD specifies all the commits reachable from the current commit (i.e. HEAD), but not from origin. For a complete list of ways to spell , see the Specifying Ranges section of gitrevisions[7].

More [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_ranges):

> The ^r1 r2 set operation appears so often that there is a shorthand for it. When you have two commits r1 and r2 (named according to the syntax explained in SPECIFYING REVISIONS above), you can ask for commits that are reachable from r2 excluding those that are reachable from r1 by ^r1 r2 and it can be written as r1..r2.

What am I doing wrong? How do I prevent listing merges that occurred between `79764fa47dde40ed8aecf203a606e64409e3f8` and `HEAD`?

[Edit]

For clarity, the history looks something like this...

```
  o   HEAD
  |  
  o  
  |  
  o   79764fa47dde40ed8aecf203a606e64409e3f895
  | 
  o 
  | 
  o 
  | 
  o 
  | 
  o 
  | 
  o   7284b1a6dea454c2023efb709a31ee9dbcde8de6
  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to check what branches were merged into the origin between two commits[...]What am I doing wrong?

You're specifying `origin` as a tip.  You specified the base and tip of the range you really want with `7284b1a6..79764fa4`, (any spellings that resolve to those two commits will do), `git log` doesn't need to look up remote urls and such so it doesn't check for a remote name there, it just resolves everything to commit IDs.

Comment: So what should I do differently? Omit the `origin` argument?

Comment: @JonCage Yes, omit the `origin` argument.  The ability to list multiple positive references is often a feature, but in this case you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the option "`--graph`" in addition to the ones you're already including :

```
git log --graph --merges --first-parent --oneline origin 7284b1a6dea454c2023efb709a31ee9dbcde8de6..79764fa47dde40ed8aecf203a606e64409e3f895
```

(**EDIT** : actually, with --first-parent, it shouldn't show much more information).

First of all, it depends on where your HEAD currently is. The fact that your log goes back up to HEAD may be a coincidence. HEAD actually points the last thing you have checked out with `git checkout`.

Also, `git log a..b` (`log` or any other command, actually) returns "everything that is reachable from **b** and that is **not** reachable from **a** ». Which means that if your history looks like something like this :

```
  o     o b
  |     |
a o     o
  |     |
  o     o
  |     |
  o     o
  |     |
  o     o
  |     |
  o     o
  |     |
  o     o
   \   /
    \ /
     o
     |
     o
     |
     o
     |
     o
```

Then `git log a..b` will actually give you the whole 7 commits on the right branch after the merge point. The chronological timestamp won't matter here, which is not forcibly clear at first because without any option, the log will display its commit set as a flat list.